# Smallest group with large independent set

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

What is the minimum size of the group containing a subset of elements $S = \{s_1,\dots,s_k\}$ satisfying the following property: There is no $i,t \in \{1,\dots,k\}$ such that $s_i^t = b_1\cdot b_2\cdot \dots \cdot b_t$ where $b_1,\dots,b_t \in S$ and not all $b_j$ are $s_i$.

There is a group of size $O(k^5)$ satisfying the property above. Can we improve this bound to $O(k)$ or $O(k^2)$?

---

Just an alternative formulation (from Włodzimierz Holsztyński):

> Let $\ S\ $ be a subset of an arbitrary finite group $\ G.\ $ An arbitrary element $\ g\in S\ $ is called a geometric mean within $\ S$
>   $$ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\quad\exists_{n\leq |S|}\exists_{x_1\ldots x_n\in S}\ \left(g^n=\prod_{t=1}^n x_t\ \ \&\ \ \{x_1\ \ldots x_n\}\ne \{g\} \right)  $$
>   This question is about the minimal possible $\ g(k)=|G|\ $ such that there is $\ S\subseteq G\ $ which has no geometric mean within $\ S,\ $ and $\ |S|=k.$

Comment: I found the original formulation more clear and I'm not sure that a post should be edited so thoroughly without its author's agreement, unless the question is really unclear (here I only found the reformulation unclear, no quantifier over $n$...).

Comment: It goes without saying that the original author is welcome to remove my version.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński In any case for the definitions to match, $n$ should be required to be $\le k$ (and $k$ shouldn't be used for two meanings).

Comment: What's an example of size $O(k^5)$? Also, is the smallest size of an abelian group with these conditions known?

Comment: Consider a group with element set $\{(a,b) \mid 0 \leq a \leq 2k^2 - 1, 0 \leq b \leq 2k^3 - 1\}$ and group operation defined as $(a,b)\cdot (c,d) = (a+b \mod 2k^2,c+d\mod 2k^3)$. Set $S = \{(i,i^2) \mid i \in \{1,\dots,k\}\}$ satisfies the property above.

Comment: Formally, $k$ under the product didn't count as a different meaning because it was not a free variable. But true that it's still better to avoid such eyesores. I'll fix this and also the vague way of $n$, no sweat. *** Done. *** Is it better now?

Comment: Slight modification needed I guess: $n$ needs to be bounded. Else, for all $s_i,s_j \in S$, there will exists a $n = lcm(order(s_i),order(s_j))$ such that $s_i^n = s_j^n$.